# There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-workbench

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `luckpermsglobal`.`glowglobal` (
);

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `luckpermsglobal`.`glowglobal` (
)

im trying to create a table but it wont let me